# Remove shower enclosure for tiling but keep shower base only

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, shower, tile, remodeling

I am remodeling my bathroom and want to change it to tile shower.

I am OK with the shower base here and I don't like the shower enclosure / doors:

[image]

Is it possible to just remove the door and the enclosure at the wall BUT keep the base? I plan to do tiling behind at the wall and put a frameless glass door.

Or I may getting myself into more complex scenario with leak, new door not fitting properly or worst things look uglier...?

Any opinion.

Thanks.

[image]

**UPDATE 1**

Basically I want to do tiling like this and keep the base (picture from Internet):

[image]

But I am not sure if my shower has the base and the wall plastic liner enclosure thing coming together as one piece, meaning it's not possible to separate them.

Any idea how such shower kit is designed?

**UPDATE 1**

OK, I committed a crime. I accidentally damage the base:

[image]

I really wanted to save the base as it does have enough lip space:

[image]

Is it possible to patch the hole with some fiberglass and sand to make it smooth? Since the glass door will be on top of it later.

**UPDATE 2**

I am working hard to save this shower base (look like a $200 cost if I have to replace). After removing the shower walls, I found out the walls mounted to the base via screw (in the back of the wall). So there are about 4 screw holes of 1/4" diameter:

[image]

Here is one small one that is hard to see:

[image]

How do I easily plug these holes from the shower base? Is there some plastic plug and I just caulk around it?

The holes are quite far from the wall so my wall tiling won't reach it to overlap the holes.

Comment: I think the chances of it looking uglier are quite slim ... ;)

Comment: Well, uglier is an overstatement but I don't know if that shower base will be ODD once everything is done. Sometime you see some work done and notice it's a bad re-use (e.g. old kitchen faucet in new kitchen is obvious). I don't know...

Comment: In the overall picture of how much time & money you're going to spend on this project, I wouldn't obsess about saving that base.  Particularly if you're going to replace the enclosure anyway.  You'll spend more getting an enclosure custom made for it then you would just starting from new with the base/enclosure combo you want.

Comment: With a surround, it is easy to be lazy and cheap, thats why they sell them, and wrap existing showers with them. For this project, for BOTH walls, you are going to want to toe in some studs and have something for the cement/backer board, this and matching it to the existing wall with that base, you're inevitably going to have some irregular lips to contend with. Spend the extra, and work a little more freely, check the drain plumbing, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your picture from the internet is nice large shower with a square inside corner. Your existing shower is much smaller with a round inside corner, a real trick to set backer and tile for a novice tile setter. To minimize the round corner, you could go to "seat height" then set backer into the corner, but you will not be getting any larger shower, it will still be the same size as before, no way to enlarge it, the pan sets the size for the shower.

If you do wish to proceed, the base is typically a separate piece from the sides. It might come loose easily if the sealant does not grip too tightly.

Comment: My idea is to remove the sides only. Then repair the 2 walls and tile on it. What do you think? Certainly another tricky part is to remount the door

Comment: It is feasible but it depends on the lip at the top of the pan. It need to be enough to keep water from passing to the framing. Hopefully an inch, no less than a 1/2". On the door reuse, it is most likely one that is from a supply house or big box store. It does not look like is is a custom cut enclosure. If it was, it would be difficult to get it to fit back. Since it is not most likely, the ones out of the box are made to take into account the differences in plumb or level from wall to wall. If you are careful keeping track of where everything goes, it will go back in.

Comment: If you go with small tiles (12x12 sheets) you can then conform to the round to a degree, otherwise I think you'll have to have an backer piece in the back to take the tile. You could then look at building built in shelving into the corner.

Comment: I edited the answer with an idea

Comment: I agree the base is usually a separate piece.i have reused doors in the past when the hinge/ frame could be removed. One thing if you enclose this it will be very dark in there so you will probably need a light. A light inside a shower would need to be listed for wet locations.+

Comment: I have damaged the base with small hole. Shall I be giving up on this idea then?

Comment: There are companies that do repairs on this type of bases, or tubs for that matter, but it may depend on the nature of the hole or crack. I just saw your edit after I commented. If it is sealed and under the door sill, it may do well....

Comment: Thanks @Jack. I added some more update for the question.

Comment: My gut feeling is to get a new one. To have it fixed by a pro, would likely cost as much as a replacement base. In this case if you do end up replacing it, you could opt for a larger shower base. I have gotten spoiled by larger than standard showers since I have installed a few in my homes we have bought and lived in.

Comment: A question on the 1/4" hole with the arrow, is it up on the vertical flange? If it is you will not have an issue with that at all. It didn't with the original sides, it will not with the new one. I would only draw concern with the one under the door sill. Carefully cleaned and using silicone caulk, neatly placed on the space may do you very well. Then place the door that you choose to use over that sealed crack, with its own recommended caulk.